# OpenGL RayCasting and Intersection with plane

Tags: opengl, c++, raycasting

I have been trying for a couple of days to raycast. I have a Renderable/Texture/Primitive/Whatever placed in the WORLD at 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, and when I click the mouse I want to know at what X,Y coordinates was the Primitive "clicked". We can safely assume that the primitive will always be at Z=0;

Basically, I should do raycasting. But it does not work. I tried finding the 3D position of the ends of the ray(near/far plane), and then compute the intersection, but it does not work. I tried getting Z from the DEPTH BUFFER,  but I always get 0 and it still does not work.

Does anyone have any fast, simple method for this?

Comment: I think you need to show us some code.

Comment: Also "does not work" is a bit vague. Does not work how? What does it do? What does it not do?